Two player coin flipping game

You and your opponent flip a coin. You go first and if you get heads, then your opponent pays you $\$30$. If you flip tails, the coin goes to your opponent. If your opponent flips heads, they win $\$30$ from you. The game goes on until one of you flips heads. How much should you pay to go first?

I have been trying to solve this, but can't come up with a solution. I built an intuition around this problem and I believe I wouldn't pay more than $\$20$ for this game. How can I solve this question?

By drawing a tree diagram, if you start first you may notice that there's a half chance that the other player pays you $30, a quarter chance that you lose $30 and a quarter chance of no transaction at all. Calculate the expected value from this

Is the game only of two coin flips ?

@trueblueanil It keeps going until one tosses a Heads.

$\texttt{You}$ wouldn't pay, ..... who are "you" ? The first player or the second ? What computation have you done for the expected value for the first player ?

If the game goes until the first heads, note that after two tails you are back at the start, so you can write an equation that has the expected value twice and solve it.

"You" is the first player. Sorry let me correct it.

Here's my attempt at a solution.
Let the sample space be sequences of H and T till the first head. $S = \{H, TH, TTH, TT...TH\}$. Now consider a random variable X that calculates the amount earned/lost by player 1.
\begin{align}
\Rightarrow X(H) &= 30 \\
X(TH) &= -30 \\
X(TTH) &= 30 \\
X(TTTH) &= -30 \\
...\\
X(TT...TH) &= 30 \mathrm{~if~even~number~of~Tails~else~} -30
\end{align}
In terms of probabilites,
\begin{align}
P(X=30) = \Sigma_{k=0,~k+=2}^{k\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{2^{k}}\frac{1}{2},~P(X=-60) = \Sigma_{k=1,~k+=2}^{k\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{2^{k}}\frac{1}{2}
\end{align}
The Expectation is,
\begin{align}
\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(X) &= 30\left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^3} + \frac{1}{2^5} + ...\right) - 30\left(\frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2^4} + \frac{1}{2^6} + ...\right)\\
\Rightarrow \mathop{\mathbb{E}}(X) &= 30 \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2^3} - \frac{1}{2^4} + ...\right) = 30\frac{1}{3} = 10
\end{align}
Therefore, player 1 should expect to win \$10 so in a fair game they should pay \$10 to go first.

Let us start by calculating the expected value when you go first, we will call this $E$. We know that there is a 1/2 chance player one wins on the first round. We also know that if player 1 doesn't win on the first round, player 2 has the same expected payout as player one did on the first round. Because this is a zero sum game, i.e. the sum of all won and lost money is zero, if player one does not win on the first round he expects a $-E$ payout. Hence we get the equation:
$$ E = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 30 - \frac{1}{2} E $$
Solving this we get $E = 10$. A "fair" game has an expected payout of 0 so we should expect anyone playing this game to pay 10 dollars to go first.
